# Does a Filipino passport holder need a visa for a business trip to China (PRC)?

Tags: visas, china, filipino-citizens, business-travel

As the title says, does a Filipino passport holder need a visa for a short business trip to China.

If it makes a difference the person is resident in the UK and also has a British passport.  So, the real question is which is easier to use?

Edit: Unfortunately the trip is off. It cannot be arranged in time.  She needed to be there on Monday.

Comment: If you’re in the UK and you have a British passport I’d imagine it’s almost certainly going to be easier to use that one. https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/china/entry-requirements

Comment: I'd guess so but the Filipino passport works better in a few Asian countries (the ASEAN ones) so I wondered whether there was a small chance that there might be some other reciprocal ones.

Answer (score 1):

With either Filipino or British nationality, you normally need a visa to visit China for business or tourism.

The exceptions are:

Filipino citizens with an APEC Business Travel Card endorsed for China can visit visa-free for up to 60 days.

Both nationalities can get a visa on arrival for tourism at certain Chinese ports, but require pre-approval by the Chinese government. For a business visit, an existing Chinese business needs to invite you (in addition to the government pre-approval). As I understand it this scheme is fairly new, but it is in Timatic, so airlines should not give you any trouble with it.